# Imputing means from aggregate function into data set for corresponding variable and group

Tags: r

I have a data set that is made up of three different groups of observations. Unfortunately there is missing data so I want to use mean imputation for different variables an input the mean of the respective group in place of the NA.

```
df<-read.csv(id, test1, test2, test3, groupnumber
1, 9, 1, 3, 1
2, 8, 2, NA, 1
3, NA, 3, NA, 2
4, 1, 3, 4, 2
5, 2, 44, NA, 2
6, 4, 4, 1, 3
7, NA, NA, NA,3 )
```

To calculate test score means I did:

```
mean1<-aggregate(test1~groupnumber, data=df, FUN = mean)
mean2<-aggregate(test2~groupnumber, data=df, FUN = mean)
mean3<-aggregate(test3~groupnumber, data=df, FUN = mean)
```

How do I input each of these means to respective groupnumber and test into the dataset to look like this below?

```
id  test1   test2  test3  groupnumber
1    9        1      3         1
2    8        2      3         1
3    1.5      3      4         2
4    1        3      4         2 
5    2        44     4         2
6    4        4      1         3
7    4        4      1         3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `dplyr` package, `mutate_at` can modify multiple columns at the same time.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(groupnumber) %>%
  mutate_at(c("test1", "test2", "test3"), ~ ifelse(is.na(.), mean(., na.rm = 
    TRUE), .))
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this code did not create the correct values shown in my example above

Comment: the same as your

Answer (score 0):

[Good post](https://statistical-programming.com/mean-imputation-for-missing-data/) on limitations and implementation of mean imputation

ASIDE: Please provide data as a reproducible data.frame such as (for your data)

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
                 test1=c(9,8,NA,1,2,4,NA),
                 test2=c(1,2,3,3,44,4,NA),
                 test3=c(3,NA,NA,4,NA,1,NA),
                 groupnumber=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3))
```

Then using for loops you can do this... although its not pretty

```
# For 2:4 where 2,3,4 are the columns with tests 1 2 and 3
for(i in 2:4){

# then for each group number value
  for(j in unique(df$groupnumber)){

# index the positions in the data frame with group number = j and column i [row,column] format
    df[which(df$groupnumber==j) , i][is.na(df[which(df$groupnumber==j) , i])] <- mean(df[which(df$groupnumber==j), i], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am not sure why my code is not working, even after I correct the df dataframe code to read "df<-read.table(header=T, sep=",", text="..........")"  ?

Comment: The code you provided works for your data set but not mine

Comment: Please post a sample of your data i.e. `head(df)`. It is hard to understand as the `read.csv` function you include in the original question doesnt run (this function is supposed to read in a file stored on your computer.

Comment: The data I created is supposed to be the same as what you have posted in your question... Are the values different in your eyes?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers appear to already address the problem but I wanted to offer a `data.table` solution. Thanks to @JMilner for the data sample.

```
library(data.table)

rm(list = ls())

df <- data.table(data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
  test1 = c(9, 8, NA, 1, 2, 4, NA),
  test2 = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 44, 4, NA),
  test3 = c(3, NA, NA, 4, NA, 1, NA),
  groupnumber = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
))


df[, `:=`(test1 = ifelse(is.na(test1), mean(test1, na.rm = TRUE), test1),
          test2 = ifelse(is.na(test2), mean(test2, na.rm = TRUE), test2),
          test3 = ifelse(is.na(test3), mean(test3, na.rm = TRUE), test3)),
   by = .(groupnumber)]


df
```

And the results:

```
> df
   id test1 test2 test3 groupnumber
1:  1   9.0     1     3           1
2:  2   8.0     2     3           1
3:  3   1.5     3     4           2
4:  4   1.0     3     4           2
5:  5   2.0    44     4           2
6:  6   4.0     4     1           3
7:  7   4.0     4     1           3
```

I suspect there are some other `data.table` tricks to do this that are a bit more dynamic but this works for the data you provided in the question.

The basic syntax for `data.table` is `dt[i, j, by]` and can be thought of in terms of `SQL` syntax where:

`i` is the `where`

`j` is the `select`

`by` is the `group by`

For more, see `?data.table`